# Google Maps Crashing (play-services-maps:)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I don't know why my Google maps crashing , but when I put this dependency in my **gradle** it crashes :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
```

**This is my Full Gradle Script :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        //   generatedDensities = []
        applicationId "company.override.huzykamz.policecopuganda"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


This is the Error am getting :

 Process: company.override.huzykamz.policecopuganda, PID: 11016
                                                                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaj; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaj' appears in /data/app/company.override.huzykamz.policecopuganda-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes49.dex)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1801)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1776)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5427)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5000)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4940)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1549)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: remove this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'`...

Comment: rafsanahmad007 is right. You shouldn´t import the complete Library, this could cause errors. You should only import the needed libraries from play services, this is stated out at the API....https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: So I remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'` completely ? and I run again ? or

Comment: use com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1 instead of using whole play services. Check this site https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup